# How to scale up Datomic transactor for throughput?

Tags: datomic

I want to test how much throughput I can possibly get out of Datomic, the bottleneck being its transactor, which does scale out.

With the rather simple transactions that I used, I got a TPS rate of *x* (I can't tell you the number due to Datomic's DeWitt clause, but to give you an idea, it's not less than 5590.92 and not more than 1,000,000,000), which I would like to boost, say by a factor of 10, so that transaction spikes do not lead to seconds of latency.

I gave my transactor (virtual) machine 12 cores, of which it only used *y* (again, I won't tell you the number, but it's somewhere between 5 and 12).

The Datomic peer creating the transactions sat on another virtual machine.

I tried both the dev storage and a remote in-memory h2 server, and the TPS figures were about the same, which is why I believe the transactor is the bottleneck, not storage. And the Datomic peer can easily generate many more transactions (in its single thread) when I just comment out the `conn.transactAsync(data)` call, so the bottleneck is not in the peer either.

**Can I make Datomic's transactor use more cores or in some other way scale up the transactor?** For my use case **it would be fine even if I could only get a temporary boost to handle transaction spikes just for a few seconds** - the high TPS rate does not need to be maintained for more than say 5 seconds.

---

Transactor settings:

```
memory-index-threshold=32m
memory-index-max=1g
object-cache-max=1g
```

Changing `memory-index-max` should not have that big of an impact, as the TPS rate in my tests is relatively stable. (As soon as memory-index-max is used up, back-pressure should reduce the TPS rate, but that's not what I'm seeing)

Transactor started with:

```
bin/transactor -Xms6g -Xmx6g config/transactor.properties
```